# пожете помочь с cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

В общем как я понял надо два cmake файла, один в главной директории, другой в исходниках. на этапе линковки становиться понятно, что библиотеки не линкуются, ну вроде понятно, как мне кажется. вот два файла.

`src`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)
project (game)
include_directories (/usr/include/freetype2)

add_executable (game
    main.cpp 
    game.cpp 
    gl_gl_3_3.cpp 
    scene-manager.cpp 
    scene.cpp 
    scene-load-start-menu.cpp 
    sprite.cpp 
    shader-proceed.cpp 
    animator.cpp 
    animate.cpp 
    actor.cpp 
    fontController.cpp 
    fontBuffer.cpp 
    button.cpp 
    sound-system.cpp 
    sound.cpp 
    language.cpp 
    isometric.cpp 
    tile.cpp 
    isometric-sprite.cpp 
    item-board.cpp 
    event-system.cpp 
    search-path.cpp 
    programmer.cpp 
    object-manager.cpp 
    item-refrigerator.cpp 
    item-door.cpp 
    human-manager.cpp 
    time-manager.cpp 
    task-manager.cpp 
    item-indoor-plant.cpp 
    palette.cpp 
    item-dinner-board.cpp 
    timer.cpp 
    scene-level-home.cpp 
    item-bed.cpp 
    item-cupboard.cpp 
    top-panel.cpp 
    clock-item-top-panel.cpp
    )

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules (SDL2 sdl2)
pkg_check_modules (GL gl)
pkg_check_modules (FREETYPE freetype2)
pkg_check_modules (OPENAL openal)
    
find_library (AUDIO audio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
    
target_link_libraries (game PUBLIC ${SDL2} ${GL} ${FREETYPE} ${OPENAL} ${AUDIO} )
```

и в root каталоге.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)
project (game)

add_subdirectory (src)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules (SDL2 sdl2)
pkg_check_modules (GL gl)
pkg_check_modules (FREETYPE freetype2)
pkg_check_modules (OPENAL openal)

find_library (AUDIO audio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)

target_link_libraries (game PUBLIC ${SDL2} ${GL} ${FREETYPE} ${OPENAL} ${AUDIO} )
```

вот пример ошибок

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/game.dir/clock-item-top-panel.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable game
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/game.dir/game.cpp.o: in function `Game::run()':
game.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_CreateContext'
/usr/bin/ld: game.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval'
```

Comment: ¿Почему содержимое cmake файлов дублировано? ¿Вы проверяли, что переменные и аргументы сборки, сгенерированные cmake, соответствуют требуемым?

Comment: @user7860670 а как правильно. я просто перешел из make, а там всё просто и понятно. а  в cmake что-то сложно, даже документацию не пойму.

Comment: обычно наоборот )

Comment: cmake намного проще ты это поймешь, если дольше поработаешь) и документация там тоже понятная, ( по началу не понятная)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде как надо

```
target_link_libraries (game ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ...
```

в файнд макросах либ обычно есть инструкция подключения

советую написать добавление исходников по маске

```
file(GLOB SOURCE &{CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
add_executable(game ${SOURCE}
```

в рут сmake удали все что после add_subdirectory, а то дубляж

в src удали project()

Comment: с `file(GLOB ` нужно быть аккуратным

Comment: везде в программировании надо быть аккуратным и следить чтобы мусорных исходников не было)

Comment: я не о том. если добавится новый файл в дереве исходников, то cmake может "не увидеть его". нужно будет удалять папку билда и запускать конфигурацию ещё раз

Comment: в любом случае, при добавлении нового файла надо будет переконфигурировать проект (почти никогда не приходилось удалять папку билд)

Comment: просто если файлы перечислить явно, то cmake обнаружит, что он стал новее и запустит этот процесс сам.

Comment: спасибо. а вы можете помочь еще вот с этим? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305972/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-cmake-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5