# Как в cmake сделать так, чтобы собранный бинарный файл был в нужном каталоге?

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня вот ещё проблема. структура проекта такая.

```
/
-CmakeLists.txt
-assets
-src/
  -*.cpp
  -CmakeLists.txt
```

я хочу чтобы когда программа собралась, бинарный файл поместился сразу в root проекта. я пробовал сделать вот такое в двух местах, но вроде как не помогло.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)
project (game)

add_subdirectory (src)



set (CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../)
set (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../)
set (PROJECT_BINARY_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../)
```

бинарик всё равно в src создается.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429656/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-directory-into-build-directory-after-make-with-cmake Также имеет смысл использовать out of source build, а то потом замучаетесь артефакты сборки подчищать.

Comment: @user7860670 ну я в clion хочу это делать, если он просто скопирует файл, запустил ли он его в root директории, или запустит в src?

Comment: Путь к запускаемому файлу следует указывать в конфигурации запуска.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать просто

```
set(OUT_DIR "bin")
set(OUT_BIN_NAME "a.out")
set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}  PROPERTIES
        FOLDER ${OUT_DIR}
        OUTPUT_NAME ${OUT_BIN_NAME}
)
```

Comment: о круто. спасибо.

Comment: это не работает.

Comment: @xverizex что именно не работает? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html читайте доку!